# Laravel Eager Loading on a single injected model

Tags: eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-7, laravel-models

I'm trying to use Laravel Eager Loading in my project and I have read the documentation about it. Every example in documentation is about getting all instances of a model with Eager Loading. But is it just about getting all instance not just a single model?
Consider this :

```
public function single(Coin $coin)
{
    $coin = $coin->with('exchanges')->get();
    return view('public.coin',compact('coin'));
}
```

It is a controller method which loads a single Coin using route binding and injects the instance and I'm trying to eager load relations of that coin. but when I access $coin in my blade view file I get a list of all coins. **So I can't eager load an injected model instance?!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading).

You can achieve what you want using:

```
public function single(Coin $coin)
{
    $coin->load('exchanges');
    return view('public.coin',compact('coin'));
}
```

Also, you can eager load relations when retrieving a single model like:

```
Coin::with('exchanges')->find($id);
```